# Regular expression for extracting excerpt from long String

Tags: regex, ios7, nsstring

I want to extract excerpt from a long string using Regular expression

**Example string:**  "" Is it possible that Germany, which beat Argentina 1-0 today to win the World Cup, that will end up as a loser in terms of economic growth? ""

**String to search: " that "**

Expected result from regex

" possible that Germany "

" rd Cup, that will end  "

I want to search the desired text from the string with  -9  and  +9  characters from the forward and the backward of the occurence of the searched string. Search string can occur multiple times within the given string.

I am working on an iOS app
using iOS 7.

I have so far created this expression with my little knowledge about reguler expressions but not able to get desired result from that

```
 " (.){0,9} (that) {0,9} "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces in your regex. If you want to capture the matched ones. Then enclose the pattern within capturing groups (ie, `()`),

```
.{9}that.{9}
```

OR

```
(?:.{9}|.{0,9})that(?:.{9}|.{0,9})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/12)

Make the preceding and following characters as optional to match the line which looks like `that will change history`

Comment: But your answer is failing when search text is in the start or end like " that will change history" in this case it will not search successfully

Comment: @DineshKaushik what's your expected result for the above example.

Comment: Search string:"that will change history"   Search text: "that"
   Expected Result:"that will chang"

Comment: yes almost that but still not exactly
Search string:"not that will change history" Search text: "that" Expected Result:"not that will chang"
Even if on either side of search string exact 9 characters are not available then show available charactyers (less than 9).

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your expression you were just missing the second "." and maybe the "?" for spaces.

```
.{0,9} ?that ?.{0,9}
```

Try that.

You can add ( ) for making groups if you want. I added the "?" to make it comply with your other example:

> " that will change history"

Comment: Can you share more examples of expected results?